# os.system(/sbin/shutdown -r now) executes first before writing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that checks a network connection. I am having problems with writing to a text file before executing the reboot command.

It runs the reboot command first before doing the script before it.

it is this part of my script.

```
else:
                        text_file.write(trigger)
                        time.sleep(1)
                        os.system("/sbin/shutdown -r now")
```

I tried adding a delay to it before letting it execute but it still runs first.

it does not write to the text file and goes directly to the

```
os.system("/sbin/shutdown -r now")
```

command

How do I get it to write to the text file first before rebooting it. Here is my script.

```
if internet_on():
    with open("reboot_checker.txt", "r+") as text_file:
                    for line in text_file:
                        if trigger in line:
                            break
                    else:
                        text_file.write(trigger)
                        time.sleep(1)
                        os.system("/sbin/shutdown -r now")
                        # print("REBOOTING")


else:
    with open("reboot_checker.txt", "r+") as text_file:
                for line in text_file:
                    if trigger in line:
                        deleteLine()
                else:
                    pass
```

Comment: I'm guessing you leave the file open with your write. If it hasn't been closed the changes will be discarded when you shutdown which will look like the bit of code for skipped.

Comment: @SimonHobbs I'll try closing the file.

Comment: @Adelin sorry I dont know.

Comment: @Adelin - `trigger` isn't being defined in the for loop. The way the asker is using `for: else:` is perfectly sensible here: read the file through, if the trigger is present, do nothing, if not, append it and reboot.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks right - i rushed into commenting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're issuing the reboot while still inside the file context manager (the `with open("...") as text_file` part). The file you've written to hasn't been closed yet, so it hasn't been flushed. Either do `text_file.flush()` before issuing your command or issue the reboot outside the context manager.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks so before I run the os.system command I'll have to add `text_file.flush()` above it?

Comment: Or refactor the `with` to a regular `text_file = open(yada yada); text_file.write(yada yada); text_file.close(); reboot`